# Protecting information in TLS client certificates

Tags: tls, certificates

If I understood correctly, when using TLS with client authentication, the client certificate is transmitted to the server in plain text. The client certificate might include personal information, (like `CN=name`, or `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: email:name@server.com`), which could be used to identify users connecting to sites secured with https.

Is there a way to securely transmit the client certificate to the server when using TLS client authentication, without exposing personal information?

Comment: FWIW TLS 1.3 in 2018 fixes this; (tentative) keyexchange is now completed and encryption enabled before authentication is done (kind of like SSH but for both directions)

Comment: See also [Does a client certificate identify the owner to unrelated websites?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199515/does-a-client-certificate-identify-the-owner-to-unrelated-websites): the threat isn't just leaking to an eavesdropper but also to a third party website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible:

- Server and client negotiate SSL *without* client certificate requirement
- Encrypted communications begin
- Server sends Hello Request to ask for a renegotiation, this one encrypted
- Client willing, another handshake ensues
- Server sends a Certificate Request to trigger client certificate authentication
- (Encrypted) handshake continues normally, and client certificate is protected by TLS.

I don't know how easily you can convince existing server implementations to do it, but the protocol allows it.  I seem to remember that there are other existing reasons and implementations that trigger a renegotiation immediately after the first (unencrypted) handshake finishes.

---

Updated to reflect @dave_thompson_085's correction, see also his comment regarding TLS 1.3.

Comment: Actually server doesn't sponaneously send ServerHello; it sends HelloRequest and if client agrees the second handshake starts with ClientHello as usual (but with Renegotiation Indication set per RFC 5746); see RFC 5246 7.4.1.1. Although now in 2018 TLS 1.3 (RFC 8446) no longer allows renegotiation at all, but does encrypt authentication on the initial handshake.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 good call, thank you for catching me on that.  I've updated to include the correction, but I suggest you add a separate answer expanding upon the TLS 1.3 changes, as 1) comments aren't trusted to stay forever and 2) I think that would be an excellent alternate answer.